# Removing string from the next closest input string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the `next closest` input to my element, Get its value and remove a string from it.

The value that I need to remove is a `data-id` of the element thats been clicked on.

Ive tried the following but this throws an error in the console which means it cannot find the input:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.deletImg', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();
  var $this = (this);

  var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
    separator = separator || ",";
    var values = list.split(separator);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i] == value) {
        values.splice(i, 1);
        return values.join(separator);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  var inp = $($this).parents().eq(1).find(".input").val();
  inp = removeValue(inp, id);
  $($this).parents().eq(1).find(".input").val(inp);
});
```

```css
.addedImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.imgHolder {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.myBlock {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.addedImg img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.deletImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
<div class="block block-strong myBlock">
  <div class="imgHolder">
    <div data-id="dd" class="addedImg">
      <div class="deletImg" data-id="dd">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,dd" />
```

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: @Barmar, your edit somehow doesn't work! please try to run the code!

Comment: Sorry, accidentally copied the CSS to the HTML box

Comment: FYI you can use `.indexOf()` to find the matching index, instead of a loop.

Comment: @Barmar, I have multiple inputs with the same class name though.

Comment: What does that have to do with the `for` loop in the function?

Comment: `var inp = $($this).parents().eq(1).find(".input")` isn't selecting anything. The input is not a descendant of any of the containing DIVs of the `deletImg` element.

Comment: @Barmar, I think somethings getting lost in the translation! nonetheless, that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Try `$(this).closest(".myBlock").next().val()`

Comment: It wasn't meant to solve the problem, it was an unrelated suggestion.

Comment: where is the value of input in `$(this).closest(".myBlock").next().val()` ?

Comment: `myBlock` is not an input to have a `val()`!

Comment: That's why `.next()` is there - the input is the next element after it.

Answer (score 1):

`$($this).parents().eq(1)` is the `.imgHolder` div. `.input` isn't a descendant of that div, so `$($this).parents().eq(1).find(".input")` doesn't find anything.

`.input` isn't contained in any of the same containers as `.deletImg`. It's the next element after the `.myBlock` container, so use `$(this).closest(".myBlock").next().val()` to get the input's value.

Also, you have to move the `.remove()` call to the end. You're removing the element that contains `$(this)`, so you can't find the container after it's disconnected from the DOM.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.deletImg', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

  var removeValue = function(list, value, separator = ",") {
    var values = list.split(separator);
    let index = values.indexOf(value);
    if (index != -1) {
      values.splice(index, 1);
      return values.join(separator);
    }
    return list;
  }
  var inp = $(this).closest(".myBlock").next().val();
  inp = removeValue(inp, id);
  $(this).closest(".myBlock").next().val(inp);

  $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();
});
```

```css
.addedImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.imgHolder {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.myBlock {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.addedImg img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.deletImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
<div class="block block-strong myBlock">
  <div class="imgHolder">
    <div data-id="dd" class="addedImg">
      <div class="deletImg" data-id="dd">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,dd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a list of all elements in the DOM traversed in a DFS way and find nearest `input` regardless to the hierarchical position in the tree.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const id = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  // Apply logic only if clicked element has 'data-id' attribute
  if (id) {
    // Convert HTMLAllCollection to Array to use indexOf, slice and find
    const all = Array.from(document.all);
    // Index of clicked element
    const idx = all.indexOf(evt.target);
    // The "closest" input would be the next input in the plain
    // list of all elements after the clicked element
    const input = all.slice(idx).find(el => el.tagName === 'INPUT');
    // Remove data-id from input value
    const value = input.value.split(',').reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (cur !== id) {
        acc.push(cur);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []).join(',');
    input.value = value;
    // Remove clicked element 
    evt.target.remove();
  }
});
```